# If a widget declared const, does it spread to its child?

Tags: flutter

Are there any practical difference between these two?

If a widget declared const, does it spread to it child?

```
Container(
    height: tabHeight,
    child: const Tab(
      icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
    ),
),
```

vs

```
Container(
    height: tabHeight,
    child: const Tab(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes
The `const` keyword is optional when obvious.

For example, we don't have to write:

```
const example = const Something(const Other());
```

We can just write:

```dart
const example = Something(Other());
```

Comment: So the framework will implicitly call the constant constructors (`const Something(const Other());` ) for us in this case?

Comment: Yes. The const keyword is optional when redundant

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the `const` keyword when initialising expressions of a `const` declaration. Below is what the official documentation says:

> The const keyword isn’t just for declaring constant variables. You can also use it to create constant values, as well as to declare constructors that create constant values. Any variable can have a constant value.
>
> `var foo = const [];`
>   You can omit const from the initializing expression of a const declaration.
>   For details, see DON’T use const redundantly.
>
> `foo = [1, 2, 3]; // Was const []`

I hope this helps.